# When calling sizeof(), there is an extra byte output after 00 (' \0 '), and the output of sizeof() is 2 more than strlen()

Tags: c++, sizeof

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
        
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        printf("%.2x", start[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x)
{
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    const char *s = "abcdef";
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(s));
    printf("%ld\n", strlen(s));
    show_bytes((byte_pointer)s, sizeof(s));
    show_bytes((byte_pointer)s, strlen(s));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
8
6
6162636465660025
616263646566
```

Why are there two more bytes? Shouldn't there be just one more ending null?

Can someone tell me what the last byte of the `sizeof` output represents?

Comment: `sizeof(const char *)` -- That gives the sizeof a char pointer, not the length.  That's basically what your code here is doing:  `printf("%ld\n", sizeof(s));`

Comment: Thanks，I understand this point. emm, I know '00' represents "null", but what the last '25' mean？

Comment: @Crepuscule_v it is just random data from surrounding memory. `s` is pointing at an array of 7 bytes but you are displaying `sizeof(s)` (8) bytes from it, so you are going out of bounds.

Comment: I got it.  It means that char * is eight bytes in size on a 64-bit machine, and the result of the `sizeof(s)` depends on type of `s` rather than content of `s`, Thanks for your answer！